# Incorrect representation of some Gurmukhi characters in Java

Tags: java, unicode, internationalization, javafx-2

I'm trying to display some text in a Java desktop application in Gurmukhi script. I have all Gurmukhi fonts installed on my system that are available on internet. I can read and write in Gurmukhi in browsers and word processors. And they all show correct presentation of almost all characters. Like...

-------image removed----------

Now the same text looks like this...

-------image removed----------

In my java application. I have noticed that SIHARI (i.e. used to present vowel sound of `i` [as in promise]) is being placed after the character and not before it.

I have searched on internet and found that Unicode recommends typing it (SIHARI - Unicode '\u0a3f') after the character but renders it before it. To me it seems like Java is blindly rendering it without following the described unicode logic.

I don't want to create 2 copies of the same text to use in 2 different places. Is there any other/better way to solve this problem?

(I have already tried explicitly changing fonts in my application, trying all available fonts, but that didn't work).

Comment: Yes, Unicode sihari is a Unicode combining character and you type it after the other character, ਧਿ, just like kanna ਸਾ

You don't mention the operating environment - Microsoft Windows XP? Ubuntu Linux 10? It may be that you need to enable language or script support.

If it's Windows and the Java Console, setting the code page to 65001 for Punjabi may help.

Comment: I'm on Windows7 x64 (although I'm using java 32 bit version).It doesn't look like Windows' issue cuz I can see correct (ਸਿ) in browser and all other apps but in my app it shows the same string as (ਸ ਿ). I mean if I type ਰਹਿਤ it shows it as ਰਹਤਿ.

Comment: Also setting java to use CP65001 (mystring.getBytes("Windows-1250"), "Windows-65001")))  is giving me this exception:

java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: Windows-65001

Comment: Windows-65001 is nothing else than UTF-8.

Comment: Thus you should use `getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))`. Notice that by using Charset's `forName(String)` you avoid try-catch clause. On the other hand, Windows 1250 is a Central European code page, it surely does not have the support for any of Indian script.

Comment: Since you are using JavaFX 2.0, I am assuming that you also use Java 7, correct?

Comment: Yes I'm using Java7_07. I tried UTF-8 too. but that is also returning the same result.

I used this code:
sTextArea.setText(new String(str.get(0).getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));

Comment: So, I created a swing project with simple interface (a jtextarea).
When I executed this new project it showed correct presentation, so I think either javafx2.2 or javafx.controls.textarea implementation is causing this.

Comment: I investigated further and found that even putting System.out.println(str.get(0));
just before (line) setting text for the textarea shows correct string in console. For labels I tried explicitly setting font just before updating their text but even that failed.

Comment: Any help? I'm going crazy now ....errr!!